# PM2 como servicio en windows (Server privado)

Tags: nodejs, pm2

me encuentro con un problema a la hora de usar PM2 para mantener viva mi aplicacion en windows, el problema es que cuando salgo de mi usuario o del servidor PM2 tambien se cierra y por ende tambien mi proceso, como puedo solucionar esto?, cabe recalcar que el server esta en una red privada y no puedo descargar archivo o paquetes dentro de este, si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradeceria.

Alguien sabe de como lidiar con esto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.